# If a pulsar moves with a high velocity should the pulses from both poles be not paralel?

Tags: special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, pulsars

If a pulsar moves with a high velocity should the pulses from both poles be not paralel to each other? Should they as a continuum form a an angle between them exactly at the very location of the pulsar instead of being paralel?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question... the pulses come from opposite poles of the pulsar and travel in opposite directions. This isn't what we would normally call "parallel". If the pulsar is moving relative to the observer, the direction of the motion matters. See http://people.physics.anu.edu.au/~cms130/TEE/site/tee/learning/what_is_sro.html for a general discussion of relativistic optics.

Comment: @EricSmith If You draw a stright line paralel to one (north) pulse would the pulse from the other (south) pole be paralel to that stright line?...

Comment: it depends on which way the pulsar is moving. If it's moving towards the north or south, then yes, the pulses would remain parallel. If it's moving towards the east or west, then no, the pulses would both be "tilted" in the direction of travel.